# Prove inequality for polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $a_0,a_1,\dotsc,a_n \in \mathbb C$ and $p(z) = a_0+a_1z+\dotso+a_nz^n$. 
How can one show that $\lvert p(z)\rvert \ge \lvert a_n\rvert\lvert z\rvert^n-\big\lvert\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{a_jz^j}\big\rvert$ ?

Comment: I've edited your question. make sure that everything is still in order

Answer (score 1):

Apply the reverse triangle inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: triangle inequality: $|A+B| \ge |A| - |B|$.